# Should a tire with cracks along the outer perimeter of the sidewall be replaced?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I have creases or small tears running throughout the perimeter of my tires.

[image]

Does this warrant replacing the tire completely?

Comment: If those tires were on my car, they would most certainly be replaced. My fear would be that the tread could separate at high speed. I would, at least, take my car to a reputable tire shop and get their opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have only seen wear like that in tires that are around 10 years old. What does the date code say? Have you ever let a rubber-band sit for years? You are risking tread separation by driving them like this. If you can afford the tires you should replace them. An accident at high speed will cost you more than the tires.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, yes.

Long answer...Yes

Comment: perfect answer....Yes

Comment: I'll elaborate on this. I had the exact same question about the two front wheels on my Pajero, years before this SO even existed. I found out the hard way when I had a blowout on the motorway / freeway, at 70MPH. 

After changing the tyre for the spare, I changed my trousers. Later that day, had the other cracked tyre replaced.

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the date of manufacture, (0811) those tires are over 4 years old.

This alone is reason enough to not use the tires as the rubber will harden over time, even if it hasn't been used, let alone with peripheral cracks like the ones shown!

Answer (score 2):

I had a almost complete tread separation on a 6 year old tire on the front while driving on the freeway.  Luckily I heard it start thumping and was able to get off the road right away.  The other front tire was about to start doing the same thing.  I replaced all 4 since they were about the same age.

I now believe it's a good idea to replace the tires after about 5 years no matter what the mileage to be safe, but that's a personal opinion.  Reading the manufacture date code on the sidewalls is easy.

[Determining the Age of a Tire](http://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=11)